# How to delete unreachable revisions from a shared repository in Bazaar

Tags: bazaar

A shared repository in Bazaar stores all the revisions of all the branches. If you delete a branch that had some unique revisions in it, those revisions will still remain in the repository, and visible by the `bzr heads --dead-only` command, from the `bzrtools` plugin.

How to delete these revisions from the shared repository?

Or, how to delete branches in a way that their unique revisions will be cleaned up from the shared repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to end up with a shared repository that does not contain these revisions is to create a new repository, and branch all the branches that you wish to keep into it.

Deleting revisions is not considered a safe operation because there may be some branch that Bazaar does not know about that depends on them.